# (Resolvido) Erro ao rodar app Android no celular mas funcionando em outros aparelhos e emulador

Tags: java, android, android-activity, emulador

**[Solução]**:
A solução encontrada foi adicionar os atributos `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"` , `android:largeHeap="true"` no manifest

---

Estou mexendo com Android faz um tempo e obtive esse erro recentemente durante uma atividade avaliativa na escola, onde tínhamos que fazer um app básico de duas activities, a segunda recebendo dados da primeira. No meu celular ele trava e fecha ao passar para segunda, nem exibindo ela, mas no aparelho da professora (ambos moto g) funcionou perfeitamente; no emulador nativo do Android, já na minha casa, também rodou perfeitamente. Gostaria de ajuda pra resolver isso, já fiz inúmeros apps com isso e é o primeiro que ocorre o problema
Desde já, grato!

Detalhes: já testei com eventos do botão dentro e fora do `onCreate` (`setOnClickListener` e definindo função normalmente e utilizando atributo `android:onClick`); tentei diminuir a imagem como sugerido

A versão do celular que rodou não tenho certeza; no emulador é uma API 25, creio que 7.1 ou 7.2 e no meu celular é 7.0, API 24

## Erros do logcat:

```
04-16 16:39:18.436 25496-25496/sqlite.studio.com.identifique E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: sqlite.studio.com.identifique, PID: 25496
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{sqlite.studio.com.identifique/sqlite.studio.com.identifique.Main2Activity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #47: Binary XML file line #47: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2659)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2724)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1473)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #47: Binary XML file line #47: Error inflating class <unknown>
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #47: Error inflating class <unknown>
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:717)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:785)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:414)
        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2418)
        at sqlite.studio.com.identifique.Main2Activity.onCreate(Main2Activity.java:21)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6672)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1140)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2612)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2724)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1473)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
     Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 35190516 byte allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 16MB until OOM
        at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:620)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:455)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1152)
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:724)
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:575)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:854)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:928)
        at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:167)
04-16 16:39:18.436 25496-25496/sqlite.studio.com.identifique E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:155)
        at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:151)
            ... 27 more
```

## XML principal:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="sqlite.studio.com.identifique.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="Bem vindo(a) ao desafio" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
        android:text="IDENTIFIQUE AS BANDEIRAS"
        android:textSize="@dimen/grande" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="246dp"
        android:layout_height="234dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="99dp"
        android:background="@drawable/inicial" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margemLateral"
        android:layout_marginBottom="146dp"
        android:text="Como gostaria de ser chamado?" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/nome"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="89dp"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/margemLateral"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/comecar"
        android:onClick="clique"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="29dp"
        android:text="começar" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

## MainActivity

```
package sqlite.studio.com.identifique;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private EditText nomeUsuario;
    private Button comecar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        nomeUsuario = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nome);
        comecar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.comecar);

    }

    public void clique(View view){
        if(verificarNome()){
            mudarActivity();

        }else{
            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            alert.setTitle("ATENÇÃO");
            alert.setMessage("Preencha o campo nome");
            alert.setNeutralButton("OK", null);
            alert.show();
        }
    }

    public void mudarActivity(){
        String usuario = nomeUsuario.getText().toString();
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Main2Activity.class);
        intent.putExtra("nomeUsuario", usuario);

        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public boolean verificarNome(){
        String nome = nomeUsuario.getText().toString();

        if(nome.isEmpty())
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
}
```

## XML secundario:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="sqlite.studio.com.identifique.Main2Activity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textoSaida"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/margemLateral"
        android:textSize="@dimen/medio"
        android:text=", identifique o nome do estado brasileiro de cada bandeira representada" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageTO"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/largura"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/altura"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margemLateral"
        android:layout_marginTop="63dp"
        android:src="@drawable/to" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageSP"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/largura"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/altura"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/margemLateral"
        android:layout_marginTop="153dp"
        android:src="@drawable/sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imagePA"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/largura"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/altura"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/margemLateral"
        android:layout_marginBottom="186dp"
        android:src="@drawable/pa" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageES"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/largura"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/altura"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/margemLateral"
        android:layout_marginBottom="94dp"
        android:src="@drawable/es" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/enviar"
        android:onClick="resultado"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/margemLateral"
        android:layout_marginBottom="28dp"
        android:text="enviar" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radio1"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/radio"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/altura"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageTO"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/margemImagem">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/matoSul"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Mato Grossso do Sul" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/tocantins"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Tocantins" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/pernambuco"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Pernambuco" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radio2"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/radio"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/altura"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/margemImagem"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageSP">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/saoPaulo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="São Paulo" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/piaui"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Piauí" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rioNorte"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Rio Grande do Norte" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radio3"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/radio"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/altura"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/margemImagem"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imagePA" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/amazonas"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Amazonas" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/roraima"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Roraima" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/paraiba"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Paraíba" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radio4"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/radio"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/altura"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/margemImagem"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageES" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/santaCatarina"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Santa Catarina" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/espiritoSanto"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Espírito Santo" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/alagoas"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Alagoas" />
    </RadioGroup>

</RelativeLayout>
```

## Main2Activity:

```
package sqlite.studio.com.identifique;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Main2Activity extends Activity {

    private TextView texto;
    private Button botao;
    private int pontos;
    private RadioButton sp, to, pa, es;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        Bundle extra = getIntent().getExtras();
        texto = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textoSaida);
        botao = (Button) findViewById(R.id.enviar);
        sp = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.saoPaulo);
        to = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.tocantins);
        es = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.espiritoSanto);
        pa = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.paraiba);

        if(extra != null){
            String nome = (String) extra.get("nomeUsuario");
            String mensagem = nome + texto.getText().toString();

            texto.setText(mensagem);
        }
    }

    public void resultado(View v){
        pontos = 0;
        onRadioButtonClicked(v);
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
        alert.setTitle("RESULTADO");
        alert.setMessage(pontos + "/4 acertos");
        alert.setNeutralButton("OK", null);
        alert.show();
    }

    public void onRadioButtonClicked(View v) {

        if(sp.isChecked()){
            pontos++;
        }

        if(es.isChecked()){
            pontos++;
        }

        if(to.isChecked()){
            pontos++;
        }

        if(pa.isChecked()){
            pontos++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Olhe o logcat e veja se aparece algum erro ao executar o aplicativo

Comment: Dei uma olhada nele, mas não consegui identificar as causas.
Editei a pergunta com os erros apresentados

Comment: Por acaso vc tem alguma imagem no seu layout? Imagens muito grandes podem fazer com que isso aconteça.

Comment: Editado, pessoal, obrigado pela atenção. Leonardo, acredito que não seja tamanho da imagem, modifiquei antes de editar e manteve o problema, além de que no celular da minha professora funcionou normalmente...

Comment: Uma possível solução [em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32244851/androidjava-lang-outofmemoryerror-failed-to-allocate-a-23970828-byte-allocatio)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se código não contém erros. Pega isso: Quando for criar um app tenha em mente As versões do Android e a API. Em compensação o Android deixa você adicionar no java ou xml um tipo dependência tipo só faz isso se android for API 24 ou superior. Quando uma aplicação funciona em uma empresa não em outra é por que a outra não tem o recurso que a primeira tem.

Comment: Obrigado! A solução encontrada foi adicionar os atributos `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"` , `android:largeHeap="true"` no manifest